# Multiple recursions in a single statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I have a question which asks, how many times '1' is printed when the code below is executed:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7


def rec(n):
    count = 1
    if n > 0:
        count += rec(n - 1) + rec(n - 1)
    print '1'
    return count        

rec(5)
```

Answer = 63

When trying to solve the above problem shown above, i was confounded with certain concepts of recursion.

1> How to approach problems with multiple recursive calls in a single statement. In the question in what order do the recursion takes place, simultaneous or one after the other.

2> I have learnt (in C) that there must always be a condition in the recursive function, which determines the number of recursions, i am not able to find such condition, so how do i find out the number of levels.

Comment: `how many times '1' is printed when the code below is executed`... Execute the code once :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, Answer is 63, But how ?

Comment: And why don't you simply do `2 * rec(n - 1)`?

Comment: @thefourtheye: because that's not the question.

Comment: @thefourtheye: because this is not the OPs code but the professors. It's an exercise.

Comment: Python evaluates expressions left to right, not in parallel.

Comment: It helps if you think of each call as a separate function, that just happens to do the same thing. `count += rec1(n - 1) + rec2(n - 1)`.

Comment: Regarding the second question - your "base condition" is if "n > 0" - in this case no recursion is called.

Comment: There is a terminating condition for the recursion: `n > 0`.

Comment: Ok....So does it execute like this...

rec(4) + rec(4), rec(3) + rec(3) , rec(2) + rec(2)....

or

rec(4) + rec(4), rec(4) + rec(3) , rec(4) + rec(2)....

Comment: Draw, on paper, a tree with root node value 5, then make 2 branches each with the immideate childhaving one less. Continue untill you have leaf nodes of 0. Since your print is doneunconditionally count all the nodes.Answer would be (n+1)^2-1

Comment: @Sylwester: You surely intended to write 2^(n+1)-1 for the number of calls. 2^6-1=63, 6^2-1=35.

Comment: @LutzL You are right. It's  `2^(n+1)-1`. I actually tested it before adding it the last minute, but the stress must have got to me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see it level by level:

```
rec(5) - you call once, print 1 once
rec(4) - you call twice ONE AFTER ANOTHER (not in parallel). Print 1 twice.
rec(3) - you call 4 times (called twice from the two rec(4)-s), print 1 four times.
rec(2) - call 8 times, print 1 eight times
rec(1) - call 16 times, print 1 sixteen times.
rec(0) - call 32 times, print 1 32 times, but no further recursion called because n==0
```

32+16+8+4+2+1=63

As in recursions, execution in performed bottom up, so your rec(0) ones will be printed first:

Printed ones:

```
rec(0) - 32
rec(1) - 16
rec(2) - 8
rec(3) - 4
rec(4) - 2
rec(5) - 1
```

As you can see, you can easily generalize the case for any n as a sum of series. Basically, this double-call recursion is no different from the simple recursion except that you don't call levels once, but 2^n times.

Answer (score 3):

above code, number of times print statement will be executed for input 5 is 63 which is correct. Lets see using the tree.Every node has 2 children because function is called 2 times in recursion.

5---->1

4  4---->2(child nodes of 5)

3  3  3  3--->4(child nodes of 4 and 4(second one)) and likewise

2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2----->8

1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1--->16

0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0--->32

all add up to 1+2+4+8+16+32=63

so number of times print will be executed is 63.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the visual representation, much easier to understand !